# Fetch a java object from mq queue

Tags: ibm-mq

I have two questions:

1. I would like to know if there is any facility available to fetch a java object dropped into mq . If yes could you please provide the code snippet to get a java object message from mqqueue.
2. Is it possible to not remove the message from the queue but read the latest message dropped. something like when you run the code it should read the latest message present in the queue.

Please let me know if there is difficulty in understanding the above queries.

Comment: 2nd query is clear, but the 1st one is not. What do you mean by dropping a "java object" in queue? What java object are you talking about? We only drop messages in queue, which could be in any form, text or binary.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your **second query** :

Yes, we can read the latest message in the queue without removing it from the queue. We call it **browsing the message**.

You will have to use few message get options like **MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST**

. After issuing MQGET with GMO, MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST, we need to issue MQGET with GMO, **MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT**. We will have to issue these MQGETs in a loop, till we reach the last message.

Everything is explained here clearly:
[http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.doc%2Ffr12610_.htm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.doc/fr12610_.htm)

Actually, it would have been far simpler if MQ API could offer something like MQGMO_BROWSE_LAST.
But still, it's fine, after all we call it a Queue(FIFO), not a stack(LIFO).

Regarding your **first query**:

What I understand from it is that you want a java class object to be put in the queue. Well, as I commented, we only put messages in a queue. Whether you are putting text messages or binary messages, MQ is flexible enough to accept both. Now, it's upto the getting application how it deals with the binary or text information in the message.

So, it's really on your implementation. I would implement it as below:

Sending side:
Say we have an object ObjToBeSent, having state of its variables as:

```
ObjToBeSent.Vara=1;
ObjToBeSent.Varb="test";
```

I will form an XML message like below and will post in the queue:

```
<ObjToBeSent>
<Vara><Integer>1</Integer></Vara>
<Varb><String>test</String></varb>
</ObjToBeSent>
```

Receiving Side:
Get the message from the queue. Parse the XML and get the values of the variables along with data type.

Declare an object say, ObjectReceived, and set values of the variables from the input message.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. suggestion to second query worked. Regarding first query the message is written as a  serialized java object and we need to deserialized and read it as a string. could you please suggest any java jms api or ibm mq api. also code snippet to perform above actions